# Verilog ignores @(posedge sd_clk) delay

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to force Verilog to wait a certain number of clock cycles before advancing in an `always` block. To initialize and SD card, I need to assert `CS` for at least 74 cycles before sending CMD0, but my waveform output shows this delay being completely ignored. I've tried unrolling the repeat block and replacing it with a behavioral `for` loop but neither of those helped. It also ignores the `@(posedge writeRDY)` line, so I don't think it's because of something specific to the clock. [This is a picture of the waveform output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqAgt.png) mosi is the data line out to the SD card.

Any ideas as to what is causing this would be very appreciated.

```
initial begin
    cs <= 1'b1;
    repeat (80) @(posedge sd_clk);
    busy <= 1'b1;
    @(posedge writeRDY);
    in_buffer <= 48'h800000000095; //CMD0. 80 -> CMD# with b_6 = 1, b_7 = 0. 32'b0 for arg, 8'h95 for CRC (checksum)
    @(posedge sd_clk);
    cs <= 1'b0;
    repeat (8) begin
        @(posedge aligned);
    end

end
```

Comment: I do not think that your waveform is relevant to the case. You need to provide better explanation. why do you think that the delay is ignored? Btw, glitches on those signals produce posedge as well. Are you sure that you are glitch-free?

Answer (score 0):

Your waveform is not very helpful because from the signals you have shown us in the test bench: `cs, sd_clk, busy, writeRDY, aligned,` only the sd_clk is shown.
You also have not told which simulator or tool you are using.

`repeat (80) @(posedge sd_clk);` should wait 80 clock cycles *but only in a test-bench*. That code can not be synthesized. 
If it is in a testbench your simulator is incorrect.